# decorators communication in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I am making a nodejs app using typescript, here is how my class looks like

```
@lib.decorators.routesRegister().version('v1')
export class mediaController extends lib.baseClasses.apiControllerAsyncBase().apiControllerAsync {


@lib.decorators.dtoRegister().dto(dto.media)
@lib.decorators.routesRegister().register({ url: "", cache:"10000" })
public async getMedia() {

    let param = {
        where: {
            status_id: {
                $ne: enums.status.DELETED
            }
        }
    }
    return this.ok(await lib.factory.createMySQLSequelizeAsyncObj('media_types').findAllAsync(param));

  }
}
```

my problem is, that when the function decorator 'register' is getting called i need the value which is being passed in the class decorator 'version', how can i attain the same ,please help me with the isse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my problem is, that when the function decorator 'register' is getting called i need the value which is being passed in the class decorator 'version'

Depends on the implementation of `routesRegister()`. The following will most likely work:

```
const routesRegister = lib.decorators.routesRegister().version('v1');
@routesRegister
export class mediaController extends lib.baseClasses.apiControllerAsyncBase().apiControllerAsync {


@lib.decorators.dtoRegister().dto(dto.media)
@routesRegister.register({ url: "", cache:"10000" })
public async getMedia() {
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but i don't want to pass the version in every function, just in the class should suffice

Comment: @PranayDutta without looking at the lib I've updated my answer :)

Comment: Looks great basarat just last help ,if u can give an example how to chain the class and function decorator

Comment: That is non trivial. This blog covers it well : http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript

Comment: Thnx basarat i had learnt decorator from this blog only :) but haven't find any decorator chaining stuff here

Answer (score 0):

So adding to basarat's answer here is how i did it

```
const routeRegister = lib.decorators.routesRegister().version('v1');


export class mediaController extends  lib.baseClasses.apiControllerAsyncBase().apiControllerAsync {


@lib.decorators.dtoRegister().dto(dto.media)
@routeRegister({ url: "", cache: "10000" })
public async getMedia() {

    let param = {
        where: {
            status_id: {
                $ne: enums.status.DELETED
            }
        }
    }
    return this.ok(await lib.factory.createMySQLSequelizeAsyncObj('media_types').findAllAsync(param));

    }

}
```

and the decorator looks like

```
   export function version(version) {

      return (route?: Object)=> {

         return (target: any, key, value) => {
             //decorator definition here
      }
    }  
 }
```